# Weird folders in my users folder in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Similar named folder is created every time I start my computer. Is this virus?

[image: in C:\Users folder]

[image: Inside the folder]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: “Similar named folder is created every time I start my computer.” - please explain does this mean that there is more than a single folder?

Comment: It looks like this is a temp folder. Could be from a dropbox/onedrive kind of service that downloads files to this folder before moving it to the actual place.

Comment: @LPChip: That's normally done in the TEMP folder. `C:\Users` is unlikely as temporary folder.

Comment: Is the folder hidden? Does it disappear later on and when? Do you have only one at a time?

Comment: Does any of the file names look familiar to you? If you think this could be caused by a virus or other malicious software, what anti-virus software do you use? If your anti-virus scanner did not find anything, you could try additional software to analyze your system, e.g. malwarebytes, adwcleaner, spybot search & destroy. Please don't use comments to add information or clarification, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: @Ramhound there was a lot of folder created with a similar name.

Comment: @harrymc This folder is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some antivirus software use similar files as bait files, which forms a layer of detection of ransomware attacks, try checking your antivirus log to make sure if it was generated by the antivirus or not.

Comment: My files in the folder looks very similar to this and I have Cyber reason. Unfortunately I cannot test uninstalling the Cyber reason because this is a company machine. Thanks for the answer. 
I have found similar issue. 
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/657749/ransomware-caught-and-stopped-but-i-cant-remove-or-id/?p=4338188

Comment: +1 Completely forgot this could be the case.